# How to find mass points and ratios in a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

How to find mass points with weights and ratios is my question.

In my class, we learned about mass points. 
First we had the given ratios of 2 side lengths.
[image: Mass point]

Given:

MC = d

MB = e

MA = f

BD:DA = 3:4

BE:EC = 2:5

Find AE:EC, BG:GE, DG:GC ratios

Then he told us to assign weights based on the ratios like

B = 3

A = 4

C = 6/5

Then multiply the weight to get rid of fractions.

Then after that he used weights of points to find ratios of other side lengths

B = 3 * 5 = 15

A = 4 * 5 = 20

C = 6/5 * 5 = 6

After that he found out the ratio of AE:EC with weights like so:

AE:EC = 6:20 = 3:10

BG:GE = 15:26

DG:GC = 35:6

Mass point = BG weight + GE weight = 15 + 26 = 41

Then weights of two points A and B added together = d

We aslo found the area of the triangles with ratios and weights.

Sorry, if I sound like I don't understand this, but I don't understand this.

Can you explain why this is so? Why uses weights to find ratios of side length?

Can someone explain me more throughly how to find mass points and give me a helpful website.